# How to nested loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have a piece of code down here, and I'm wondering if I can make this simpler with list comprehension in Python...

```
T: str = 'XY'
combinations: list = [] # Make an empty list

for i in range(len(T)):
    for j in range(len(T)): combinations.append((T[i], T[j])) # (T[i], T[j]) is act as a tuple here
```

How can I simplify this into a better for loop without taking so many times to loop around `i` and `j`? Much help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in List-comprehension version of the code you have written:

```py
>>> [(T[i], T[j]) for j in range(len(T)) for i in range(len(T))]
[('X', 'X'), ('Y', 'X'), ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Y')]
```

Modified List-comprehension without len and range, but iterating the string itself:

```py
>>> [(x,y) for x in T for y in T]
[('X', 'X'), ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'X'), ('Y', 'Y')]
```

If you want to use `product` function standard library `itertools`:

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(T, repeat=2))
[('X', 'X'), ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'X'), ('Y', 'Y')]
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght I can not agree you more on that. Plus, why to re-invent a wheel if its already there?

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro... The reason why I'm re-implementing here even though I already knew that the product is already implemented in the itertools module, is because I want to see how this thing works through my own implementation, and it seems like it's already that easy... Thanks once again, bro...